# Access function return value in joining table column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

The partial select statement is:

```
SELECT t1.Column1, t1.Column2, **"Column3"** = dbo.FunctionName(Column1, Column2)
  FROM Table1 t1
```

Now I wanted to left join Table2 in above query but join needs to be **"Column3"** = Table2.**Column3**; something like as below query which does not work and how to achieve that.

```
SELECT t1.Column1, t1.Column2, Column3 = dbo.FunctionName(Column1, Column2),
       t2.Abc, t2.bcd
  FROM Table1 t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.Column3 = ????
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try

```
SELECT 
          t1.Column1, 
          t1.Column2, 
          Column3 = dbo.FunctionName(Column1, Column2)
          t2.Abc, t2.bcd
FROM
          Table1 t1 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 
          ON t2.Column3 = dbo.FunctionName(t1.Column1, t1.Column2)
```

This should also work

```
SELECT 
      t1.Column1, 
      t1.Column2, 
      t1.Column3,  
      t2.Abc, 
      t2.bcd
 FROM 
    Table2 t2 LEFT JOIN JOIN 
 (SELECT t1.Column1, t1.Column2, Column3 = dbo.FunctionName(Column1, Column2)
  FROM Table1 t1) t1
  ON t2.Column3 = t1.Column3
```